# The name _stringify_path is not defined

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, plotly, stringify

I'm using Plotly and I got a error when I am trying to read a CSV:

`data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')`

I'm getting this error:

`name '_stringify_path' is not defined`

Comment: 1. Show you're entire code.
2. Inform which version of `plotly` you installed on your machine.
3. Provide a sample from this dataset (`data.csv`) which you're trying to read.

Comment: I faced this with the version 0.25.3 but it disappeared after restarting the console / kernel.